# How to set, search location in Google map to country specific

Tags: android

I am working with Google map in my application. I need to set the search location for a specific country(eg India). For example If i search any place (eg. paris) it should search only in India. Is there any method to search, without passing country name India in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

componentRestrictions can be used to restrict results to specific groups. Currently, you can use componentRestrictions to filter by country. The country must be passed as as a two character, ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 compatible country code

```
var input = document.getElementById('searchTextField');
var options = {
   bounds: defaultBounds,
   types: ['establishment']
};

autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

Source: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#adding_autocomplete